# My HTML Template is not receiving all of my component variables in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

So my issue is I have 3 variables I would like to send to my html template but it only ever picks up one of them.

**My html template** looks like this.

```
<div class="page-data">
    <form method="post" action="api/roles/edit/{{role?.ID}}" name="{{role?.ID}}">

        <table cellpadding="11">
            <tr>
                <div class="label"> Role Name </div>
                    <input type="text" name="role_name" value={{role?.ROLE_NAME}}>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="label"> Description</div>
                    <input type="text" name="description" value={{role?.DESCRIPTION}}>

                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="label" *ngIf="role?.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'Y'"> Active Record </div>
                    <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value="Y" checked> Active
                    <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value="N"> Inactive
                <div *ngIf="role?.ACTIVE_FLAG === 'N'">
                    <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value = "Y"> Active
                    <input type="radio" name="active_flag" value= "N" checked> Inactive
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="label"> Active Modules</div>
        <select id="modules_applied" name="module_name">
            <option value="none"> None</option>
            <option *ngFor="#module of modules" value = "{{module.MODULE_NAME}}">{{module.MODULE_NAME}}</option>
        </select>

        <div class="data-table">

            <table id="modules_table" border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7"></table>

            <br>
            <br>

        </div>
        <div class="label"> Inactive Modules </div>
        <select id="new_mods_select" name="new_modules">
            <option value="none"> None</option>
            <option *ngFor="#module of new_modules" value = "{{module.MODULE_NAME}}">{{module.MODULE_NAME}}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="data-table">

            <table id="new_modules_table" border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7"></table>

            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</div>
```

and **my component**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import {RoleService} from './../services/roles.services';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {RouteParams, RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'edit_role',
  providers: [RoleService],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: 'app/roles/edit_role.html'
})
export class RoleEdit implements OnInit{

    role: any;
    modules: any;
    new_modules: any;
    params: any;

    constructor(private _roleService: RoleService, params:RouteParams){
        this.params = params.get('id');
    };

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getEditRoles(this.params);
    };

    getEditRoles(id){
        this._roleService.getEditRoles(id).subscribe(role_edit =>
            {this.role = role_edit.data[0],
            this.modules = role_edit.modules[0],
            this.new_modules = role_edit.new_modules[0]},
            error => {
                console.log('error logged:');
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    };
}
```

**My error**

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' in [modules
>   in RoleEdit@29:11]

I just learned about the question marks for async calls with: {{role?.ID}}.  It does look like ngFor loops don't like those though, and I think that is most likely where my problem is.  Thanks!

**Edit:**

So here is more of the code, what is in my role.services, and my JSON.

Here is my **role.services**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RoleService {


    constructor(public http: Http) {

    }

    getRoles(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/roles/')
            .map((response => response.json().data));
    }

    getEditRoles(id){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/roles/edit/' +id)
            .map((response => response.json()))
    }
}
```

And here is my **JSON** I am trying to capture.

```
{
  new_modules: [
    {
      MODULE_NAME: "user_roles"
    }
  ],
  modules: [
     {
      ROLE_ID: 6,
      MODULE_NAME: "roles",
      INSERT_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
      UPDATE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
      DELETE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
      QUERY_ONLY: "Y"
    },
    {
      ROLE_ID: 6,
      MODULE_NAME: "test_mod",
      INSERT_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
      UPDATE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
      DELETE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
      QUERY_ONLY: "N"
    },
    {
      ROLE_ID: 6,
      MODULE_NAME: "users",
      INSERT_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
      UPDATE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
      DELETE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
      QUERY_ONLY: "Y"
    }
  ],
 data: [
    {
      ID: 6,
      ROLE_NAME: "Fire",
      DESCRIPTION: "Something hot",
      ACTIVE_FLAG: "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I guess some of the fields you bind to don't hold actual data but a promise or a subscription but not actual data. Maybe you need to add an `| async` pipe but it's hard to tell from your code because it's not known what the calls return.

Comment: I've updated my code to be more helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I get this when trying to use the async pipe.  `Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' in [modules | async in RoleEdit@29:11]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to and crediting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870197/angular2-simple-http-service-injection#answer-33892203) it appears that you may be missing the

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

for your Http request. Since your code snippets do not include the `getEditRoles` code in the `RoleService` I cannot confirm that this is in fact missing. But my suspicion is that you are using making the Http request and then returning it. Your code for that method should be something like to following for it to work:

```
public getEditRoles(id: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('some.url', {id: id})
               .map(res => res.json());
}
```

This will ensure that the `Response` object from the Http call gets converted into JSON for use in your component.

**Update**

With your updated question I now see some discrepancies in your code. In your component you have this line

```
this.modules = role_edit.modules[0]
```

Which means that you are assigning the **array** `modules` the value of the first **object** in the `modules` array of your json.

So at this moment `this.modules` would have a value of

```
{
  ROLE_ID: 6,
  MODULE_NAME: "roles",
  INSERT_ALLOWED_FLAG: "Y",
  UPDATE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
  DELETE_ALLOWED_FLAG: "N",
  QUERY_ONLY: "Y"
}
```

Which then you are attempting to iterate over, but as it is not an array, the framework errors.

For this to work as you expect change

```
this.modules = role_edit.modules[0]
```

to

```
this.modules = role_edit.modules
```

Which will assign the entire array to `this.modules` instead of only the first item.

Comment: I updated my post to be more accurate, I really appreciate all the help you've given me.  I just bought an Angular2 book from ng2 that I plan to go through, but this is not in there!

Comment: You are awesome man, I really appreciate it.  I feel bad that I keep asking these mundane questions!

Comment: @MorganG only critique I have is to try to tailor your code blocks to your question instead of posting full files or big chunks, its an acquired skill. Keep up the coding and best of luck in your creations!